# magento internal server error with admin only

Tags: magento, overriding, magento-1.5, internal-server-error

I am getting internal server error in my magento admin. It was working fine and i did not make any change in the files but suddenly i got the internal server error in my admin. My front end is working fine. 
URL -- http://highnoteperformance.com/
Admin URL - http://highnoteperformance.com/admin

I have also magento-cleanip.php but in thi i am getting following result -

----------------------- CLEANUP START -------------------------

******** *SETTING PERMISSIONS* **********
Setting all folder permissions to 755
Setting all file permissions to 644
Setting pear permissions to 550

Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: No such file or directory in /home/highnote/public_html/magento-cleanup.php on line 45

************ CLEARING CACHE ******************
Clearing var/cache
Clearing var/session

******* *CHECKING FOR EXTENSIONS* ******
-= WARNING =- Overrides or extensions exist in the app/code/local folder
-= WARNING =- Overrides or extensions exist in the app/code/community folder

------------------- CLEANUP COMPLETED in:2.1583 seconds -----------------

But still admin is not working.... Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

1. Backup your `app/etc/modules` folder and delete the XML files one by one. This will eliminate the possibility of a custom extension messing with the admin.
2. Check your PHP error log - it may tell you where exactly the issue is.

Comment: Yes i have check the error log but it was showing some error like Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'highnote_db.core_file_storage' doesn't exist' in /home/highnote/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228  But currently there is no error in error log file as welll.

Answer (score 0):

You changed the admin URL. Have a look into the table core_config_data via phpmyadmin and search for "*baseurl" and "admin/url/*" entries.

Read more:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/65439/

Comment: Yes i have checked it is fne. Actually the site was working fine previously but suddenly i got the error in admin only. Still i do not have any problem in fontend.